# Angle dependencies between equilateral and right-angled triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, angle

Given an equilateral triangle $\triangle ABC$ and a right-angled triangle $\triangle ABD$ where $\angle ADB$ is the right angle and, therefore, the hypotenuse $AB$ is shared with the $\triangle ABC$. Let's say that the angle $\angle DAB$ is $\theta$ and the length of $AB$ is $d$. The problem:

> How do you define angle $\angle ADC$ in terms of $\theta$? And also how do you define length of $DC$ in terms of $\theta$ and $d$? Basically I need to figure out their functions.

Here's essentially what it looks like [image]

Can't seem to figure out how to derive the solution myself, and I don't even know how to describe this problem so that I could Google it.

In the real world, I got inspired by a tripod that was standing in the corner of my room with two of it's legs touching the walls. It got me thinking: if I rotated the tripod around the corner so that the two legs would keep touching the walls what trajectory would the third leg follow? And so the problem just stuck in my head for half a day.

If it's a known generic problem I would like to know what it's called, if not then what steps are necessary to derive the solution? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: $\;AD= d \cos \theta\,$ then in $\,\triangle ACD\,$ you know two sides and the angle between them, so you can solve for the third side and angles.

Comment: It's hard to read your diagram (the labels are far too small for me anyway).  But...well, $\overline {AD}=d\cos \theta$ and, of course, $\overline {AC}=d$ so you can solve $\Delta ACD$ completely.

Comment: Pt D placement is arbitrary unless the direction of AD or BD is given.

Comment: @herbsteinberg $D$ must be on a half-circle with diameter $AB$, and is unique for a given $\theta \in (0, \pi/2).$

Comment: Thanks, I now understand what I need to work out to get to the solution I want. I was lost in all the triangles and payed more attention to $\triangle DBE$ and $\triangle DEA$ ($E$ being the intersection of $DC$ and $AB$) having completely forgotten everything about solving SAS triangles.

Comment: @dxiv  We are both right.  For a specific direction, the angle is set.